Maclaurin expansion "used" at $x \ne 0$
I have an expression in the following way, that I am trying to simplify
$$A = f(0) - \frac{f^{(1)}(0)}{2!} + \frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{3!} - ...$$
where $f^{(n)}(x)$ stands for $\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}} f(x)$.
If $g(x) = \int f(x)$ (noting that it can contain the constant of integration),
I can still write it as
$$\begin{align} A &= g^{(1)}(0) - \frac{g^{(2)}(0)}{2!} + \frac{g^{(3)}(0)}{3!} - ... \\
& = g(0) - g(0) + g^{(1)}(0) - \frac{g^{(2)}(0)}{2!} + \frac{g^{(3)}(0)}{3!} - ... \\
&= g(0) - \left\{  g(0) - g^{(1)}(0) + \frac{g^{(2)}(0)}{2!} - \frac{g^{(3)}(0)}{3!} - ... \right\} \\
&= g(0) - \left.\left\{  g(0) + g^{(1)}(0) x + \frac{g^{(2)}(0)}{2!} x^2 + \frac{g^{(3)}(0)}{3!} x^3 + ... \right\} \right|_{x=-1}\\
\end{align}$$
Question: I am not sure how to proceed after this. One one hand I am tempted to call the expression in the $\left\{ \right\}$ as $g(-1)$, but Maclaurin expansion (by definition expanded at $x=0$), substituted with $x=-1$ doesn't make sense. What is the right approach to simplify this? Or is my question impossible to answer without specifying $f(x)$?
Note: I am aware of a similar question Here, but I am still not clear.

You seem to confuse the argument/input (here: $x$) of the function with the point of expansion (here: $0$), which are independent of each others $-$ actually, the expansion consists in computing $g(x)$ from the value $g(0)$ with successive corrective terms.
The expression inside the brackets corresponds to $g(x = -1)$ indeed. Since the constant of integration is arbitrary, you may choose $g(0) = 0$ by setting $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$, hence finally
$$
A = -g(-1) = -\int_0^{-1} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1 f(-x) \,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
with the change of variable $t = -x$.

Thanks. If we don't assume anything about $g(0$, are you saying $A = g(0)-g(-1)$ is a valid expression? Let me work it through my actual $f$ and $g$ once again. I asked this question only because it didn't seem to match. But I might have made a mistake in my computation

@Srini   Yes, but then we are talking about different functions $g$, given that antiderivatives differ from a constant quantity. If we denote my primitive by $G$, with the condition $G(0) = 0$, and an unspecified antiderivative of $f$ by $g$, then there exists a constant $C$ such that $g(x) = G(x) + C$, and more concretely $C = g(0)$, hence $A = g(0) - g(-1) = g(0) - (G(-1)+g(0)) = -G(-1)$. Actually, the constant $g(0)$ inside the brackets (i.e. inside $g(-1)$) cancels with the one outside the brackets, so that it is equivalent to consider directly an antiderivative vanishing at the origin.
